# Steam - If I backup games in Ubuntu, and install a new distro, can restore those games in the new distro?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, backup, games, steam

So I've been loving Kubuntu however, currently all my games are in Ubuntu. I want to fully transfer over to Kubuntu at the moment but I don't want to take all the time to fully download my games again. Basically I just want to know if linux game backups in steam are basically "universal." I know you can't transfer files in different operating systems like a backup from windows cannot go be restored in linux or osx. But I am curious to know if that can be applied to linux distros.

TBH I feel like I know the answer since the only main difference in kubuntu is the fact that it uses KDE instead of gnome. But i'd like some info from those of you who may have already done this.

Answer (score 1):

Steam has a function where you can back up anything you select. If you open up the Steam browser, click the Steam drop-down menu in the top left corner and select Backup and Restore Games. You can follow the prompts from there to select what you want to back up, and where to back it up to, such as a secondary hard drive or USB drive.

Once you have everything moved over to Kubuntu, you can then repeat the same process and initiate the restore procedure.

Comment: Excellent! I've used the backup and restore function but wasn't sure if it would work even between distros. I figured it would in the instance of moving to a different flavor of ubuntu, but I think asking now would save me a lot of time later haha! Thanks!